# What's the use of the "taunt" key?

Tags: dustforce

I can't figure what the "Taunt" key is doing?

[image: Dustforce options screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This key only works in multiplayer games.  If you press it while playing solo, nothing will happen.  All it does is make your character do a little dance or animation; a 'taunt' to the other player.